# Get information from SQLite (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am new in Android Studio and I just started to work with the SQLite
I created a SQLite file (db) and I created a function that put some data in the table:

```
 public String FirstInsert()
    {
        String meassage = new String();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COL_2,"hi how are you?");
        cv.put(COL_3,"blabla");
        cv.put(COL_4,"blabla");
        cv.put(COL_5,"blabla");
        cv.put(COL_6,"blabla");
        cv.put(COL_7,"blabla");
        cv.put(COL_8,"blabla");
        cv.put(COL_9,"blabla");
        cv.put(COL_10,"blabla");
        cv.put(COL_11,"blabla");


        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        if(result == -1)
        {
            meassage = new String("Bad");
        }
        else
        {
            meassage = new String("Good");
        }
        return meassage;

    }
```

I want the do more spesific select that take only one item, the COL_2 and the row is number that I get so I  wrote this code:

```
public Cursor GetQuestions(int num)
    {
        //num++;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT QUESTION FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "ORDER BY " +  num + "ASC LIMIT 1",null);
        return res;
    }
```

this is the right code? and if it is why I got an error here too?

Thank you very much for trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,that's because not having space between words of sqlite code
and it's better to close your cursor and your db after every query
like this

```
res.close();
db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that i had to do space in the SQLite code like this:

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT QUESTION FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "**&**ORDER BY " +  num + "**&**ASC LIMIT 1",null);
```

**&** = space (I write & to show where I added the spaces.